# Answered but unaccepted but upvoted questions?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Shouldn't it be closed or accepted by moderator?

its a bit annoying new users ask question get their answers and leave without accepting an answer.

Comment: That will never happen so you basically have two options: 1) Stop caring about accepts. 2) Stop answering hit-and-run questions.

Comment: And of like 1,000 other duplicates, although I haven't found one on this side of the split.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Mysticial its not about caring though lol! and I was sure it was discussed am relatively new! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be closed or accepted by moderator?

Why should it be closed if it's a good question? Closing because the OP didn't accept an answer simply does not make sense. And a moderator force-accepting an answer, even more so.

From the [Help Center page on accepting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer**, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

As the page says, not all users accept answers. Some people just ask a question and run away, others might just wait a while longer to see if there are any more answers, some will just not accept because none of the solutions worked for them. **Accepting an answer is not strictly necessary.**

In the end, accept mark simply shows which one of the solutions was chosen by the question-asker. It has no direct relation to the total usefulness of the answer. The usefulness of the post is determined by the community and this feedback is shown to the user using upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: I should have checked the help section! thanks @amal-murali

Comment: One use case that isn't mentioned by the Help Center page is the case where the user obviously did come back to check the answer, and left a comment like "thanks, worked a charm!", and there was no further activity, but still didn't accept the answer. It's not just about rep, answers that are de facto accepted but not marked as such are an annoyance because they don't show up as accepted when you are browsing the questions. There could be an option to "flag as asker indicated as accepted" and if it still isn't marked accepted a week later it appears in a queue for a mod to do the honours.

Comment: That's a good suggestion @samgak. Maybe you could post it as a feature-request? (if there isn't already one).