# How to deal with people that don't accept answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, unaccepted-answer

Lately I noticed the following on SO:

- Users ask questions and disappear (question isn't accepted)
- Users who never accept an answer or never post the solution (if they found it on their own)

How can we deal with this? Perhaps add a 'Not satisfied' flag?

Comment: People do this all the time. There isn't anything you can do about it.

Comment: Several of my own questions remain unanswered. Simply because none of the answers are correct/satisfactory.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you're right. What i meant it helps if you google something and you find a pertinent question for your solution but with these unaccepted questions it's not easy.

Comment: Then upvote it. The acceptance mark *only indicates that it worked for the asker*. I would go for the community "accept" (via upvotes) over the green check any day.

Comment: You are posting answers in the [android] tag.  It is [pretty notorious](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252860/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag), adjust your expectations downwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused, however, by your second item. How do *you* know if they did indeed find an answer? If they did find one, it would indeed be nice to let us know.. but surely we cannot make judgement on them if they disappeared.

That said, there is no obligation for the user to accept any answer. None, whatsoever. It is the user's prerogative. It is up to the user to decide. They *should* select an answer if it indeed solved the problem. But we should not force it upon them, it has been discussed before. See -

[Answered but unaccepted but upvoted questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260260/answered-but-unaccepted-but-upvoted-questions/260267#260267)

Comment: Of course there is no obligation, it would be nicer to close it or let other know that it isn't solved.

Comment: It's quite common that users leave a "thank you, this is exactly what I needed" type comment, but never accept it. In those cases, you do know that they found an answer.